# system center operations manager (SCOM) role combinations

Tags: windows, monitoring, system-center, scom

We are evaluating system center operations manager 2007 R2 product, and would like to know what all roles can be combined onto single server.

Like root management server and reporting servers can be on one box or not?

my environment is like 450 servers mostly Exchange and Domain Controllers plus few OCS servers.

Answer (score 1):

For 450 Servers that need monitoring i would not place all roles on 1 server altough it is possible. If that server breaks down you will be lost until you manage to restore it. Also it might be a bit much for one server to handle that load by it self.

I would recommend a 4 server setup. 1 MSSQL+Reporting+OpsMgrWeb, 1RMS, 2 MS+ACS. 
I would setup MSSQL with reporting services to run the databases for OpsMgr, OpsMgr DW, and ACS. If you all ready have reporting services installed somewhere, dont install the opsMgr reporting on that server. It will change things making the normal reporting service useless for you and break old reports.

Distribute the RMS encrpytion key and import them on the MS servers so they can be promoted to RMS if the RMS dies. Run all agents to the MS servers with automatic failover.
Install the Audit Collection Service if needed on the MS servers.

Keep the Load of clients to a minimum on the RMS as it is the only thing that accesses the DB trough the Database Accesss Service(SDK)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good suggestions overall.  I would probably start with a 2 server setup (1 RMS, 1 SQL & Reporting). ACS isn't a first step item honestly in my opinion.  Beyond that I would recommend a dedicated ACS Collector server running SQL Enterprise (online indexing will save your bacon here) with a boatload of fast disk space (no seriously, I've seen 1GB of data per day for a single DC). If you need the redundancy, a second MS makes sense, but I don't see a need to keep agents away from the RMS in this scale.